# Issue overriding the default constructor of the UIButton Class?

Tags: objective-c, class, uibutton, subclass

When an object is placed on a View Controller, it is initialised. I want to know if it's possible for you to place a UIButton on a Storyboard, with a custom class that is a subclass of the UIButton class, and have it automatically initialise with custom properties and run some custom methods - as defined in the custom class - instead of having to type out the method that modifies the properties within the View Controller's class.

Effectively, I'm trying to save space within my View Controller's class by having the custom button automatically construct itself as any ordinary UIButton does, but with custom properties and methods that are also run.

I'm unsure how to approach solving my problem, I essentially want to have the setupButton method run within an overridden constructor.

```
@implementation TransitionButton

@synthesize borderRadius, borderWidth, borderColor, highlightColor;

- (void)setupButton
{
    borderRadius = 5;
    borderWidth = 2;
    borderColor = [TransitionButton customRedColor];
    highlightColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self addBorder];
    [self setupEventEffects];
}

- (void)setupEventEffects
{
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(highlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(unhighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
}

- (void)addBorder
{
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.cornerRadius = borderRadius;
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
}

- (void)highlight
{
    self.layer.borderColor = highlightColor.CGColor;
    self.titleLabel.textColor = highlightColor;
}

- (void)unhighlight
{
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
    self.titleLabel.textColor = borderColor;
}
```

Comment: The designated initializer for UIButtons, I believe, is `-initWithFrame:frameRect`. You can override that to set some properties. However, if you're going to be mucking with visual aspects you may need to override the button's  `-drawRect:` method and do those there.

Comment: Hmm, can you elaborate on that please. Also, if the initialiser is -initWithFrame, surely I should be able to include all of my property modifications within an if (self) block inside the initialiser?

Comment: “I essentially want to have the setupButton method run within an overridden constructor.”. So do that. Implement `initWithCoder` (or `awakeFromNib`) and call `setupButton`. What’s the problem?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storyboards do not initialize their objects with `init`. They initialize with `initWithCoder:`, so that's what you need to implement if you want customization from a Storyboard.

Something along these lines:

```
- (instancetype) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder: coder];
    [self setupButton];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of a mock implementation?

Comment: Ah okay, thanks for this. Reassures me that my implementation was also correct (I used the self = inside an if statement)

Comment: `self = [super init]` vs `if (self = [super init])` is a very old style debate. If `self` is nil, then the rest falls through and returns nil.